# How to save a model and then deploy the model using AI Platform Notebooks only or through UI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am not able to access the `Cloud Console` or install/run `gcloud` locally because of firewall issues. Even attaching to a Compute Engine VM instance fails. However, starting a Notebook from AI Platform and working on it in the browser is the only thing working in my environment.

To test a demo and to understand hands-on how to save and deploy a model, I wrote some very basic code for Boston Housing dataset. However the code fails at the part where I call `joblib.dump(model, filename)`. The exact same same code however works without exception locally.

I have a general idea that I need to save/deploy model to Google Cloud Storage and somehow access it from there. But the instructions I find keep referring to some shell environment which I cannot access at the moment.

Q1.) Is there a way to save the model in Cloud Storage **without leaving the Notebook environment**?
Q2.) Also, how do I again access the model for prediction?

*Most Important Question.)* Will getting the above 2 questions working, lead me to have a **Deployed Model** ?

Sample code you can use -

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
import joblib

boston_dataset = datasets.load_boston()
X = boston_dataset['data']
Y = boston_dataset['target']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=5)

lin_model = LinearRegression()
lin_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
y_train_predict = lin_model.predict(X_train)
rmse = (np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_train, y_train_predict)))
r2 = r2_score(Y_train, y_train_predict)
y_test_predict = lin_model.predict(X_test)

# root mean square error of the model
rmse = (np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(Y_test, y_test_predict)))

# r-squared score of the model
r2 = r2_score(Y_test, y_test_predict)

print('RMSE is {}'.format(rmse))
print('R2 score is {}'.format(r2))

filename = 'model.pkl'
joblib.dump(lin_model, filename) # <- this line raises exception
loaded_model = joblib.load(filename)
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, Y_test)
print(result)
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can run bash command on Notebook. So, what is your issue/challenge?

Comment: In Jupyter notebook you can do `! gcloud command` using bang before the gcloud command, this command is executed from inside the notebook...